# How do you calculate slack space?

Tags: byte, drive, hard-drive

A file of size 12,500 bytes is to be stored on a hard disk drive where the sector size is 512 bytes, and a cluster consists of 8 sectors. How much slack space is there once the file has been saved?

Answer (score 0):

## A few things to know:

- Slack space is the leftover sectors and bytes from a cluster allocation.
- Hard drives understand sectors and are nearly universally 512 bytes as far as logical block addressing goes.
- OS (operating systems) understand clusters, which are groups of sectors.  This amount of sectors can vary between OS and file system.
- The OS DOES NOT understand sectors.  The hard drive DOES NOT understand clusters.  But they are both terms needed for calculating slack space.

### Example 1

Given:

- Sector Size: 512 bytes (basically the ONLY sector size these days)
- cluster size: 8 sectors
- file size: 2560 bytes

In this scenario, when disk space is allocated to store the file, the smallest amount that the OS can read/write MUST be 8 sectors or 4096 bytes.
To find slack space:

1. first find your cluster size in bytes.  Cluster == 8 sectors.

   ∴ allotment is **4096**.
2. then find if the file size is larger or smaller than that allotment size.
   2560 bytes < 4096.
   ∴ only **one cluster** is needed to save this file
3. subtract the file size from the cluster size and you have slack space.
   4096 - 2560 == **1536 bytes (or 3 sectors) of slack space.**

### Example 2

Given:

- Sector Size: 512 bytes
- cluster size: 16 sectors
- file size: 61440 bytes

In this scenario, when disk space is allocated to store the file, the smallest amount that the OS can read/write MUST be 16 sectors or 8192 bytes.
Let's work through the same process:

1. first find your cluster size in bytes.  Cluster == 16 sectors.

   ∴ allotment is **8192**.
2. then find if the file size is larger or smaller than that allotment size.
   61440 bytes > 8192.

   ∴ **several clusters are needed** to save this file.
3. since this file is larger, divide it by the cluster size in bytes.

   61440 / 8192 == **7.5 clusters** required to save this file.

   This isn't a nice round number, so we will have to **round up**.  Recall that the OS cannot write LESS than a whole cluster and if we allot less whole clusters than necessary, we won't save the file.

   ∴ we require **8 clusters**.
4. find the size in bytes of your allotment size.

   8 clusters * 8192 == **65536**.
5. subtract the file size from the cluster allotment and you have slack space.

   65536 - 61440  == **4096 bytes (or 4 sectors) of slack space**.

Try it.